# Nested Jade template black with

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I'm struggling with nested inheritance in Jade. There's probably a better way to approach it than what I'm currently trying.

I have the following file structure:

```
views
 |
 |-index.jade
 |-layout.jade
 |-login.jade
```

My `layout.jade` looks like this:

```
html
  body
    block content
```

My `index.jade` looks like this:

```
extends layout

block content
    .page-container
    .page-login
       block login
    .page-footer
```

My `login.jade` looks like this:

```
extends index

block login
    welcome #{user} <do some logic here>
```

I render it using like this:

```
res.render('index', { title: 'Welcome Home', user: 'Guest#342' });
```

Nothing is showing up in the login block. I've been googling for an hour but can't find any documentation or example regarding nested template blocks. More specifically, passing variable down to the child templates.

I'm guessing it's not possible. Am I missing something or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why you are not include your login.jade into your index.jade ? It'll be better.

Comment: I ended up changing my layout to a more flat design much like you suggested.

Comment: Cool ! In fact, I usually have a layout.jade, and some pages like index.jade, article etc with a lot of includes. And it's working great.

Answer (score 1):

Since `login` extends `index`, you should render `login`:

```
res.render('login', { ... });
```

Comment: Yeah, I thought about doing this, but the way I have it setup, I wanted to use multiple nested blocks so if I render login, then I won't be able to see the other sub-blocks on the page. I'm realizing the way I'm using the template inheritance is not really the way its designed to be used. In the end I changed my layout to be more flat, like @David suggest above.

Comment: @Boso if that's the case, including blocks makes more sense :)